# Differences in Mean Relative Error of prediction when using feature scaling

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am running a LSTM neural network with Keras. In order to do so I am scaling the features of the dataset using scikit-learn's `MinMaxScaler` to scale them all from 0 to 1. In order to build a time-series for the LSTM NN (using [this Machine Learning Mastery's algorithm](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)), I am grouping my records by the key and applying the scaling to the values of each group, then run the model and then rescale both the prediction and the original target like so:

**Time-series creator**

```
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg
```

**Time-series preparation**

```
g = players.groupby('Player')
n_feat = 34
n_window = 3
final = []
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
for player, values in g:
    
    values = values.drop(['Player'], axis=1).to_numpy()
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    values = scaler.fit_transform(values)
    reframed = series_to_supervised(values, n_window, 1)
    final.append(reframed)

time_series = concat(final, axis=0)
train_records = int(a.shape[0] * 0.66)

train = time_series[:train_records].to_numpy()
test = time_series[train_records:].to_numpy()

n_obs = n_feat * n_window
train_X, train_y = train[:, :n_obs], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :n_obs], test[:, -1]

test_predict = test[:, n_obs:]

train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], n_window, n_feat))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_window, n_feat))
```

**Model training and execution**

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), activation='softsign'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), activation='softsign'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1))
model.add(layers.Activation('linear'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=40, batch_size=50, verbose=0, shuffle=False)

yhat = model.predict(test_X)
```

Now, when I check the error by calculating the Mean Relative Error of the prediction I get different values depending on whether I execute the operation with the scaled values or if I re-scale them:

```
# Without scaling
rel_error = 2 * np.absolute(test_y - yhat) / (np.absolute(test_y) + np.absolute(yhat))
print(f"{round(rel_error.mean() * 100, 2)}% +/- {round(rel_error.std() * 100, 2)}%")

## Result: 61.52% +/- 48.21%

# Re-scaling
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_feat*3))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((test_X[:, -(n_feat):-1], yhat), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,-1:]

# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_X[:, -(n_feat):-1], test_y), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,-1:]

# calculate RMSE
rel_error = 2 * np.absolute(inv_y - inv_yhat) / (np.absolute(inv_y) + np.absolute(inv_yhat))
print(f"{round(rel_error.mean() * 100, 2)}% +/- {round(rel_error.std() * 100, 2)}%")

## Result: 49.41% +/- 34.19%
```

I have seen more drastic differences when fitting a different dataset with another model, like 18% after rescaling vs. 70% without rescaling.

What's the reason for this difference? Is it because the scaled values of the target variable may be too small and carry some sort of operation error?